# Copy CTOR vs assignment operator to initialize an object (performance)

Tags: c++, initialization

One of my past employers 15 years experienced star developer claims that Copy CTOR to create an object is superior over assignment operator. 
As such,

```
Object x = Object(5, "My Object"); // is inefficient
Object y(5, "My Object"); // is efficient
```

However with the following test code I see that compiler always calls Copy CTOR for the first line above. 
Such as:

```
class test_ctor
{
    public:
    explicit
    test_ctor(int x):_x(x)
   {
       std::cout << "CTOR: " << _x << "\n";
   }

   test_ctor & operator = (test_ctor const & y)
   {
       std::cout << "operator =: " << _x << "\n";
       _x = y._x;
       return *this;
   }
  private:
      int _x;
  };

 int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
     test_ctor const test = test_ctor(2);
     return 0; 
 }
```

Since my ex employer thinks he is the star developer, I am wondering what am I missing. Are there any compiler will do differently (think MS Windows 7 / Visual Studio 2010+, And OpenSuse 10+ OS/Compilers)?

Comment: Your ex-employer doesn't know what he's talking about: constructor elision has been allowed even with if there would be side-effects since C++11, and mandated in some cases in C++11 and in more cases in C++17.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: If he that said initializing an object directly with the constructor is generally better than creating an object and then assigning to it, then he does know what he's talking about actually. If he identified the line `Object x = Object(5, "My Object");` as a call to the assignment operator, then that is incorrect of course. But the way the question is structured, that seems to be a point of confusion of the OP, not his employer. However, it's an understandable mistake. It has the `=` symbol in it, afterall.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You are also confused with your answer. Either a certain approach will be acceptable or not, at best there may be certain platform or compiler that could be non-conformant. Here Direct initialization and copy initialization are both same all the time. Telling it otherwise is a crap and putting it in a rule book is nothing more than stupidity. In many C++98 compiler would do copy elision. (See the comment below). As these techniques are nothing new. C++11 and C++17 are just making the behavior a formal one.

Comment: @SyedRaihan: I have no idea why your comment is directed at me, as it doesn't appear to have anything to do with what I said. And it's not at all clear to me what you think I'm confused about.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I am not directing to you but your comment. The right answer will be the first comment or prove that any compiler on a platform will behave differently. Otherwise one does not understand C++. It is not that I am teaching how to invoke CTOR or assignment operator e.t.c. It is about what a professional should know about the outcome of two statements in the question. If these are known to produce identical results on windows and linux then there are no points to argue which is better.

Comment: @SyedRaihan: I still don't know what your comment has to do with mine. To be clear, yes, the 2 lines in your code snippet will almost certainly produce identical binary code. Nobody has claimed otherwise. Not even your former employer, if you are correctly relaying his claim to us. Because what your employer said has to do with the difference between copy constructing, and assigning. But neither of the lines in your example contain an assignment, so the fact that they produce identical binary is not relevant to your former employer's claim.

Comment: Now, on the other hand, if it was your employer, and not you, that provided this code example to demonstrate his point, then as I said, he would be mistaken in that case. But it is not clear whether that code snippet is originally from him, or from you.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley To be specific just the team lead by Pranesh Mupala and Rob Stewart and Orest are that stupid to choose one style over another. Susquehanna in general do not follow their coding guidelines. So my point is not to show off but rather as a learning post. You take my word or not it does not matter.

Comment: However your comment suggests that somehow these two statement are different. When I say different, it is what will be the compiler output from these statements. Nobody but you here tried to make a point that somehow these are different in your original post. (And also my ex-team). There is a new coding guideline for C++ from Hurb Sutter and Stroustrup. People should learn from them. Otherwise any one is free to have benefit of doubt whether I have made things up or not, as you suggested. That is not my problem. I am here to learn if I was wrong or not.

Comment: @SyedRaihan: You seem to be having trouble comprehending. Not once, not in my original post, nor in any posts that followed did I suggest that the two code snippets were different. You also seem to think that I am accusing you of making things up. I never did. Please read more carefully in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, there's no assignment; they're all initializations. So assignmenet operator is not involved here.

`Object x = Object(5, "My Object");` means to direct-initialize a temporary `Object` then use it to copy-initialize `x`; `Object y(5, "My Object");` means to direct-initialize `y`. So the latter is more efficient; in concept.

According to [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (since C++17 it's guaranteed), the two initialization styles have the same effect in fact; the objects are both direct-initialized (the copy operation is omitted).

Comment: Thanks. I know it. More over the code under review in my ex-employer had specifically was set for C++11 compilation mode. I wish my ex-employer would see the post and the comments before they hire another engineer and then let him go as they did for 4 engineers in just 2 years. :) Since I tested my code with Mac OS using latest CLANG, I wanted to be sure about it, by posting it in the community.

Comment: The point is to clarify understanding on C++ constructors. It is not that I do not know the answer already but knowing that other experts agreed on the given use of constructors. However the team managed by David Bozzini and John Barun (Pranesh Mupala, Robert Stewart and Orest Zborowski) lack the knowledge and skill to manage software engineer 3 and above. Their level at best software engineer 2 and best suited to teach C++ keywords and syntaxes to interns and software engineer 1. Code works with C++98.